# string operator + (overloaded) different behavior for char array and string.in cpp

Tags: c++, arrays, string, char, operator-overloading

I tried merging 2 arrays using string operator.
Following case works fine, + operator accepts char* and string.

```
    string s = "";;
    char a[5] = { 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't' };
    char b[6] = { 's', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd' };
    s = a + string(b);
```

But this case does not work fine when I pass char* and string. I was confused why is it so?

```
    string s = "";;
    char a[5] = { 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't' };
    char b[6] = { 's', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd' };
    s = a + "{";
```

could someone please explain.

Comment: It is out of your question, but you have to declare size of chars including NULL chars. Variable a and b should be char a[6], and char b[7].

Answer (score 1):

Because `"{"` is not `std::string`, but `const char[2]` (including the null terminator char) which could decay to `const char*`. Then `a + "{"` is just pointer arithmetic (addition) which is invalid.

You need to change either of the operand to `std::string` to make the [`operator+` for `std::string`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%2B) to be called. e.g.

```
a + std::string("{");
```

or use [literals](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator%22%22s) (since C++14).

```
a + "{"s;
```

Answer (score 0):

C-style strings have a nul terminator (`'\0'`) at the end. Library code that handles them uses the nul terminator to find the end of the string.

```
const char *a = "abc";
```

Here, `"abc"` is an array of 4 `char`, as if you had written

```
const char *a = { 'a', 'b', 'c', '\0' );
```

If you leave out the `'\0'` the library code won't know that you are interested only in the three characters that you put in the initializer. It simply won't work right. Formally, the behavior is undefined; anything the program does is legal.

To make this code work right, add a nul terminator to each of the C-style strings:

```
char a[] = { 'f', 'i', 'r', 's', 't', '\0' };
char b[] = { 's', 'e', 'c', 'o', 'n', 'd', '\0' };
```

Note that I removed the array size from `a[5]` and `b[6]`. The compiler will figure it out from the initializer. The type of `a` is "array of 6 `char`", and the type of `b` is "array of 7 `char`".

The second problem, even after this is fixed, is that

```
std::string s = a + "{"
```

doesn't do what it looks like. `"{"` is a C-style string (i.e., an array of `char`). There is no `+` operator for two C-style strings. To concatenate two C-style strings into an object of type `std::string` you can either do two separate operations:

```
std::string s = a;
s += "{";
```

or you can explicitly convert one (or both) of the C-style strings to `std::string`:

```
std::string s = std::string(a) + "{";
```

I generally prefer the first approach, but the second is certainly reasonable.

Comment: Thank you so much, can you please tell me how do you people know so much about programming, I mean what should I do to gain so much knowledge and clear concepts. Can you please help? I am a computer engineer with 1 year of experience

Comment: @aromahola -- read a good book or two, keep on writing code, and don't be shy about asking for help.

Comment: Thank you  for replying. okay sure, if possible could you please suggest any good books with practical approaches, design patterns and cpp core concepts? I have read all these topics from geeksforgeeks. and I can see there are plenty of other books on these topics.

Comment: @aromahola -- yeah, I knew I'd left that out. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) is the usual link.